Imcompatible Qt library when running nsight compute ncu-ui
I am using Ubuntu 22.04 (x86_64 architecture) and my goal is to run NVIDIA Nsight Compute ncu-ui command to visualize some GPU performance profiling outcomes. When I run ncu-ui, the following message pops out:
Cannot mix incompatible Qt library (5.15.3) with this library (5.15.2)

I know there is a relevant solution posted here and that the Qt library package version is 5.15.3 for Ubuntu 22.04 according to the Debian package. However, the solution does not work in my case because:

Its recommended package is no longer available in here, but I instead do

$ wget -q 'http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/q/qtbase-opensource-src/libqt5network5_5.15.2+dfsg-9+deb11u1_amd64.deb'

to download the 5.15.2 version.

When unpacking the downloaded .deb, the following error message shows up:

Preparing to unpack libqt5network5_5.15.2+dfsg-9+deb11u1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libqt5network5:amd64 (5.15.2+dfsg-9+deb11u1) over (5.15.2+dfsg-9+deb11u1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt5network5:amd64:
 libqt5network5:amd64 depends on qtbase-abi-5-15-2; however:
  Package qtbase-abi-5-15-2 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libqt5network5:amd64 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.8) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libqt5network5:amd64

I have searched for a while on how I can resolve such an issue, but it seems that the already built Qt 5.15.3 keeps throwing dependency error. Is there a risk if I remove Qt 5.15.3 or is there another way to resolve such an issue?
